# textarea value is empty or not - check with jquery not working, why

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this code, `comment` is id of `textarea`:

```
<textarea id="comment">      </textarea>
```

js

```
var comment = $('#comment').val();
if(comment.length === 0){
    alert('empty');
    return;
}else{
    alert('not empty');
}
```

it is giving me not empty even if it is empty. why is this? i cannot check like `!=""` because whitespace will pass the check and i would have to check for all whitespaces then

please help

Comment: Are you basically asking how to check if the value is empty except for whitespace?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove space in your textarea or trim the value

```
<textarea id="comment"></textarea>
```

or

```
var comment = $.trim($('#comment').val());
```

Also btw if you are returning after `if` you dont need an `else`

```
 var comment = $.trim($('#comment').val());
if(comment.length == 0){
    alert('empty');
    return;}

 alert('not empty');
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the `else`. thanks dude. working perfectly now

Answer (score 3):

I bet it does the opposite of what you expect, right?

I think you need to study how it works, even if it is a logical problem. If the length of the string is 0 it is empty, otherwise it is not.

```
var comment = $.trim($('#comment').val());
if(comment.length === 0){
    alert('empty');
    return;
}
alert('not empty');
```

Comment: yeah, this is what i am checking. if comment length is 0, then comment must be empty. am i wrong?

Comment: No you are not, but in your code you wrote `comment.length !== 0`, **!==** means "is not equal"!

Comment: oh sh*** :D you are right. corrected the question! but now working. thanks man ;)

Comment: yeaah, it was sooo confusing here :D

Comment: @LightStyle - +1 for the `!==` bit - Wonder how i missed it!

Answer (score 2):

Should work if you `trim()` the value before checking its length.

```
var comment = $.trim($('#comment').val());
if(comment.length !== 0) {
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to trim the value before checking and it can be done in one line

```
alert($.trim($('#comment').val()) == "" ? "Empty" : "Not Empty");
```